# Add custom parenthesis before and after selection

Tags: latex, automation

I use emacs to write latex and I need to enclose a lot of small expression in braces ( \{ and \} for latex) I would like to select the text to enclose and have some command that would add { before the selected text and } after. Is it possible with a simple command?
Thank you.

EDIT: Corrected { } to \{ \}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951797/wrapping-selecting-text-in-enclosing-characters-in-emacs

Comment: Do you use AUCTeX or the built-in LaTeX mode?

Comment: the built-in latex mode, I believe, the mode is called LaTeX/P in the gui, I am on an office laptop so I am not the one that configured emacs.